# How to convert to next day when currents date format is "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, date

I have a date in my application which has this format :

```
"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
```

The user chooses a day from a picker and the date is always converted to this format. From this format how can i get the date after exactly 24 hours?

For example if the date is `Mon 24 , 2012 17:44:33` i need the code to transform it to `Tue 25 , 2012 17:44:33`.

Comment: I think you mean "EEE dd , yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to create a `NSDate` from your string:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:<FORMAT_OF_DATE_STRING>];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:<DATE_STRING>];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Use the following code to add days to a `NSDate`:

```
    NSDate *today =<YOUR_DATE>        
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    /*
     Create a date components to represent the number of days to add to the current date.         
     The weekday value for Sunday in the Gregorian calendar is 1, so add 1 from the number of days to subtract from the date in question.  (If today is Sunday, add 0 days.)    
     */
    NSDateComponents *componentsToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    if(day<7)
    {
       [componentsToAdd setDay: day];
    }

    NSDate *calculateDay = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:componentsToAdd
                                                      toDate:today options:0];
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

1. Read the [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039-SW1).
2. Use a date formatter to generate a date from the string.
3. Add one day to the date.
4. Use a date formatter to generate a string from your new date.

Comment: So i need to get the timestamp from this date , add 84600000 which are the ms for one day and the transform it back? Thanks for the downvote :)

Comment: @user1511244 I didn't downvote (though I'm tempted). Why would you add milliseconds when time intervals are always specified in seconds? Please start with step 1 above.

Comment: @user1511244 There's even a section in the manual I linked called [Adding Components to a Date](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW3).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you need to set up the date formatter:

```
NSString *dateString = @"Tue 24 , 2012 17:44:33";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE dd , yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *theDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];

theDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(60*60*24) sinceDate:theDate];

NSString *newDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:theDate];

NSLog(@"%@",newDate);
```

The console returns:

```
2012-07-18 09:26:28.395 TesterProject[71645:f803] Wed 25 , 2012 17:44:33
```

You really should include a month though, because it will just take the current month if you do not, and that can throw off your day of the week.

I used the actual format of the dates you entered, not the incorrect format that you typed in your question.  For information on date formatting here is the [unicode standards](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

For information on `NSDateFormatter` here is the Apple documentation: [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

EDIT:  Here is an alternate implementation:

```
NSString *dateString = @"Tue 24 , 2012 17:44:33";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE dd , yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *theDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[offsetComponents setDay:1];

theDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:theDate options:0];

NSString *newDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:theDate];

NSLog(@"%@",newDate);
```

It returns the exact same thing.

Comment: This is not how Apple recommend to do it. See the answer by Caleb

Comment: But, why?  The only problem the above has is that the `dateString` does not include a month and can, therefore, throw off the day.  That is not fixed by apple's implementation, which I added as an edit above.  My original completes 2-4 of Caleb's answer just fine, and in fewer steps.

Comment: You need to specify gregorian calendar. Try doing your calculation with a hindu calendar. From wikipedia: "In the Hindu calendar, the day starts with local sunrise. It is allotted five "properties", called angas."

Comment: I tried it with almost all the calendars in NSLocale and got the exact same result on about a dozen different random date Strings.  The reason it doesn't matter is because he has not set a month.  The format he gave works just fine with what I answered.  My assumptions were safe based on his format.

Comment: Every calendar around the world has the same unit of measurement for a day? Wow, I didn't know that, interesting. Try a bigger unit perhaps (chinese new year for example vs. gregorian new year). My point is Apple don't recommend this method because it is calendar dependent.